# Agregar imagen a RadAlert Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como puedo agregar una imagen a un RadAlert? intento esto pero no me funciona..

```
 RadWindowManager1.RadAlert("SuccessFully Autenticated", 200, 100, "Access Avaliable", null, "~/View/Imagenes/exito.JPG");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Efrain, buen día, podrías comentarnos mayores detalles sobre lo que andas haciendo? Es MVC o WebForms? Cómo se llama el componente de DevExpress que estás usando? Qué tipo de mensaje quieres mostrar? saludos

Comment: Solo quiero agregar una imagen a el RadAlert, fijate edite mi pregunta ..agregue una imagen

Comment: estás seguro que es DevExpress, no será componente de Telerik?

Comment: busque la telerick y no la encontre ...

Comment: Porque en DevExpress no hay, en cambio en Telerik sí: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/window/details/calling-radalert-from-codebehind-(all-versions-of-radwindow) Ahora, si la etiqueta no existe, sería de ayuda para todos que elimines la que no corresponde: devexpress. Mientras tanto, vamo leyendo la documentación, si encuentro algo lo estaré publicando :D

Comment: de casualidad una imagen te refieres a cambiar el ícono?

Comment: Al lado del boton ok  deberia salir la imagen que esta en el path "~/View/Imagenes/exito.JPG"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La imagen no deberias ubicarla dentro de la carpeta `~/View` sino que deberias ponerla dentro de `Content`

[Folder Structure of ASP.Net MVC Project](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/folder-structure-of-Asp-Net-mvc-project/)

en esa misma carpeta por lo general tambien se definen los css

Si revisas la doc del [RadAlert Dialog](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/alert,-confirm,-prompt-dialogs/radalert-dialog)

en el ejemplo que la doc plantea veras que la imagen si se visualiza, pero debes validar que la imagen es accesible y si la ubicas dentro de la carpeta View no lo es

Recuerda que puedes usar la `Developer Tools` del Browser, al cual accedes con F12, con la solapa `Network` podrias validar si la imagen que defiens se puede acceder o si esta fallando

Comment: Ok...Pruebo y comento....